# Flutter - argument type 'Complexity/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Complexity/*2*/

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I'm trying to run this app with two enum parameters sent to a screen like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/meal_item.dart';
import '../models/meal.dart';

class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/category-meals';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];

    final categoryMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
      print('a');
      return meal.categories.contains(categoryId);
    }).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return MealItem(
            id: categoryMeals[index].id,
            title: categoryMeals[index].title,
            imageUrl: categoryMeals[index].imageUrl,
            duration: categoryMeals[index].duration,
            complexity: categoryMeals[index].complexity,
            affordability: categoryMeals[index].affordability,
          );
        },
        itemCount: categoryMeals.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the Meal.dart file :

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

enum Complexity {
  Simple,
  Challenging,
  Hard,
}

enum Affordability {
  Affordable,
  Pricey,
  Luxurious,
}

class Meal {
  final String id;
  final List<String> categories;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<String> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  final int duration;
  final Complexity complexity;
  final Affordability affordability;
  final bool isGlutenFree;
  final bool isLactoseFree;
  final bool isVegan;
  final bool isVegetarian;

  const Meal({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.categories,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    @required this.ingredients,
    @required this.steps,
    @required this.duration,
    @required this.complexity,
    @required this.affordability,
    @required this.isGlutenFree,
    @required this.isLactoseFree,
    @required this.isVegan,
    @required this.isVegetarian,
  });
}
```

the app is running fine if I comment this two lines of the first code above :

```
complexity: categoryMeals[index].complexity,
affordability: categoryMeals[index].affordability,
```

and even after running if I uncomment them and reload it using hot reload it works fine without any problems except if I running the app without commenting them then I'm getting this error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/screens/category_meals_screen.dart:31:46: Error: The argument type 'Complexity/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Complexity/*2*/'.
 - 'Complexity/*1*/' is from 'lib/models/meal.dart'.
 - 'Complexity/*2*/' is from 'package:deliMeals/models/meal.dart' ('lib/models/meal.dart').
            complexity: categoryMeals[index].complexity,
                                             ^
lib/screens/category_meals_screen.dart:32:49: Error: The argument type 'Affordability/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Affordability/*2*/'.
 - 'Affordability/*1*/' is from 'lib/models/meal.dart'.
 - 'Affordability/*2*/' is from 'package:deliMeals/models/meal.dart' ('lib/models/meal.dart').
            affordability: categoryMeals[index].affordability,
                                                ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: In the ListView.builder you are instantiating MealItem, but your class is Meal. Is it another class or is the name just wrong?

Comment: @ClaudioCastro thanks for your answer, I've solved it and you can take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

the problem is ambiguous but it solved by replacing the import line

```
import '../dummy_data.dart';
```

with this one

```
import 'package:deliMeals/dummy_data.dart';
```

can anyone explain what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

hi please try this way ...  change your import syntax of this file `CategoryMealsScreen`

from `import '../models/meal.dart'` to
`package:deliMeals/models/meal.dart`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've already tried with no luck ((:

Comment: @mohandes Thank you for the help, I have faced the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If this is regarding the flutter tutorial, this can be caused by inconsistent includes. Check all your files and make sure all your includes are consistent

See inconsistency below.

```
import '/models/meal.dart'; (file1)
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/models/Meal.dart'; (file2)
```

change this to

```
import '/models/meal.dart'; (file1)
import '/models/meal.dart'; (file2)
```

Also make sure there aren't duplicate file names. Last close the project in Visual Code by closing the folder and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out the problem is in dummy_data.dart file and the import './models/Meal.dart'; has problem.

try changing

import './models/Meal.dart'; to
import './models/meal.dart';

with lowercase 'm' and problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, then I change the import syntax of every file from     `import '../models/meal.dart`'  to    `package:deliMeals/models/meal.dart` , I removed the `../` and wrote the whole path in every file

then I run in Terminal

```
flutter clean
flutter Pub get
```

And it worked fine